# Massive Query with inner join not returning any data

Tags: massive

I'm using the Massive Query method to write a simple join query against an Oracle database. This is my code with the query simplified even further by taking out some columns:

```
        dynamic logTable = new DynamicModel("mydatabase", "table1");
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("select CONTACT_ID from table1 inner join table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID ");
        sb.Append("where table1.ID=:0");

        dynamic dbResult = logTable.Query(sb.ToString(), id);
```

The following code gives me an error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CONTACT_ID'

```
string id = dbResult.CONTACT_ID.ToString();
```

If I take the exact query and run it through sqldeveloper, I get back the expected results. If I try to Query through Massive without a join, I get back an object I can work with.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake! I was expecting my query to return only one record, but forgot that Query returns IEnumerable. Solution is to take First() or loop over the results.